# Sencha Touch - scrollable side menu with the same width as children

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a side menu in Sencha Touch which when showed up has a width the same as the widest child. As I understand this behavior is by default in Sencha Touch and that's what I need.

Now I would like that my side menu will also be scrollable. When I use the property 'scrollable' with my menu I have to use the property 'width' or it won't show up at all.

The question is how to make the width of my side menu to be equal to the widest child as it was before but with the scrollable property? So basically I just want absolutely the same behavior as it was before adding the scrollable property along with width. (I don't want it would be of a constant size as the width of children change dynamically depending on viewport and I don't want it would be in percents).

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Test',

launch: function() {

    // Create basic panel
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            title: 'Native Side Menu',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                iconCls: 'list',
                handler: function() {
                    Ext.Viewport.toggleMenu('left');
                }
            }]
        }],
        listeners: {

            swipe: {
                element: 'element',
                fn: function(event, node, options, eOpts) {
                    if (event.direction == 'right') {
                        Ext.Viewport.showMenu('left');
                    } else {
                        Ext.Viewport.hideMenu('left');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Create native side menu
    var sideMenu = Ext.create('Ext.Menu', {
        //scrollable : true,      // try to run it commented to see the behavior without 
        //width: '220px',         // scrollable property and then uncomment to see what I mean 
        items: [
            { text: 'Settings' },
            { text: 'New Item' },
            { text: 'Star' }
        ]
    });


    // Add side menu to viewport
    Ext.Viewport.setMenu(sideMenu, {
        side: 'left',
        reveal: true
    });

}
});
```

Comment: Add some commented screenshots to help us understand the problem.

Comment: I added the code. Run it with 2 lines commented first, then uncomment and run to see the new behavior.